# Should Audit columns be testable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have been tasked with adding audit columns to a specific table.

```
public interface IAuditedEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
    DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; }
}

public class MyEntity: IAuditedEntity
{
    private readonly DateTime _utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get => _utcNow; private set { } }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get => _utcNow; private set { } }
}
```

I was thinking of filling the values by overriding `SaveChangesAsync` using `ChangeTracker`.

One of my co-workers suggests these values should be testable and I am not sure how that can be done with this implementation.

I have also never seen a testable auto-generated field and am wondering what would be the best approach for such (or does this requirement makes sense at all).

Comment: If you are using a unit of work, or repository pattern, you can inject something like a IDateTimeProvider which will allow you to access the current time and mock it in your tests.

Comment: @Neil so you suggest to "manually" feed those values to each entity?

Comment: I think what @Neil means is to create a **scoped** service that has a DateTime now value that is set in the constructor which will thus provide the same date when accessed

Comment: @JamalSalman i am doing that on the class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while no answer satisfies my requirements atm,
as a temporary solution, i have decided to go with the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GetUtcDate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GetUtcDate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

since values are not manually fed into the entity, there is no need to test it.
if a better answer comes along, i would considering changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Both `CreatedBy` and `LastUpdatedBy` should be exactly, and precisely, defined in your test cases. Hence, I believe both can be asserted in the test cases.

Similarly, unless you have some weird timing requirements it should be fairly easy to put constraints on the `CreatedAt` and `LastUpdatedAt` fields too.

I would further suggest that if you are on EFCore, then, use in-memory database for easier readback and asserts here.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
repository.Insert(entity);

// At this point, I think both the entity itself and if you can read it back from the store should have acceptable values or the test fails.
Assert.IsTrue(entity.CreatedBy == "me");
Assert.IsTrue(entity.LastUpdatedBy == "me");
Assert.IsTrue((now - entity.CreatedAt).TotalMilliseconds <= tolerance);
Assert.IsTrue((now - entity.LastUpdatedAt).TotalMilliseconds <= tolerance);

var newEntity = repository.Get(entity.Id);
// same tests here.

// Repeat similarly for update, and ensure created attributes don't change.
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would test such? (pseudo code is good enough). since i can not figure out how to create the date initially to be able to compare it after saving.

Comment: the values generated on `SaveChanges` will be different from `now`, since a few milliseconds will pass.

Comment: That's controlled by the tolerance parameter, it will depend upon the characteristics of the store.

Comment: "Precisely" for the user test case is using, "tolerance" for the time stamps since they are not tightly controlled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a bit what you mean by auto-generated. I'm not sure how you could test them if they were auto-generated by the database, but if you populate the values in the `SaveChangesAsync` method, then you could define an interface for the task, and then mock it up in your tests. Something like

```
public interface IAuditSource
{
    public DateTime Now { get; }

    public string LoggedOnUser { get; }
}

public class AuditSource : IAuditSource
{
    public DateTime Now => DateTime.Now;

    public string LoggedOnUser => // however you authenticate
}


public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private IAuditSource _auditSource;

    public MyDbContext(IAuditSource auditSource): base() {}

    public override int SaveChangesAsync()
    {
         // If Changed Entities are IAuditedEntity
         // Set values using _auditSource
    }
}


public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var auditSource = new Mock<IAuditSource>()
    auditSource.Setup(x => x.Now).Returns(new DateTime(2020, 01, 28))
    var context = new MyDbContext(auditSource.Object)
}
```

Comment: `public DateTime Now => DateTime.Now;` and `public DateTime Modified => DateTime.Now;` would have a difference in milliseconds (or nanoseconds) and the test should include not just the date but the actual `DateTime` value

Comment: I agree about the date - but this is just a quickly typed example. DateTime.Now has about 15 milliseconds accuracy IIRC correctly, so if you assign it twice in quick succession then it is very likely to be the same actual value

Comment: i already know the implementation (as described in my question), i am looking for a test (or change of logic) that could test those values.